# Mapping classes in typescript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

let`s say you want to map a class to a certain React component or any other value using typescript:

```
import { BooleanField } from "../rendering/components/field/BooleanField";
import { MoneyField } from "../rendering/components/field/MoneyField";
import { TextField } from "../rendering/components/field/TextField";
import BooleanWrapper from "../form/values/BooleanWrapper";
import MoneyWrapper from "../form/values/MoneyWrapper";
import StringWrapper from "../form/values/StringWrapper";

export const fieldComponentsMapping = [
  {
    value: BooleanWrapper,
    component: BooleanField
  },
  {
    value: MoneyWrapper,
    component: MoneyField
  },
  {
    value: StringWrapper,
    component: TextField
  }
];
```

What would the type of `fieldComponentsMapping` be?

It is not something like `FieldComponentMapping[]`:

```
interface FieldComponentMapping {
  value: ValueWrapper;
  component: StatelessComponent;
}
```

Since we are not mapping instances to each other but constructors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way of typing a constructor is to use an interface with a `new ()` key in it. For example, if we had a class named `SomeClass`, this would be the type of that class, to say that doing `new` on this creates an instance of that class.

```
interface SomeClassConstructor {
  new (): SomeClass
}
```

So, assuming all of your `*Wrapper` classes extend a `ValueWrapper` class, here's what it would be:

```
interface ValueWrapperConstructor {
  new (): ValueWrapper
}

interface FieldComponentMapping {
  value: ValueWrapperConstructor
  component: StatelessComponent
}
```

Alternatively, this form also works, and looks a little more succinct if you prefer.

```
type ValueWrapperConstructor = new () => ValueWrapper
```

https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html#difference-between-the-static-and-instance-sides-of-classes

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use

```
interface FieldComponentMapping {
  value: typeof ValueWrapper;
  component: typeof StatelessComponent;
}
```

`typeof` will give you the constructor type for class types.

Comment: Thank you for your response Raphael, unfortunatly I already tried that and it results in: 
`TS2693: 'ValueWrapper' only refers to a type, but is being used as a value here.`

Comment: It would work if ValueWrapper is a class, but it is an interface.

Comment: In that case there is probably a separate interface for the `ValueWrapper` constructors, something like `ValueWrapperStatic`. It’s the interface that contains the definition for `new`.